# What's the best way of excluding specific @Bean from @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot, testing

What's the best way of excluding `javax.servlet.Filter`s from specific `@WebMvcTest`s in a granular way when they're defined via `@Bean` instead of `@Component`?

More information:
`@WebMvcTest` `excludeFilters` works fine for excluding beans defined via component scanning (i.e. `@Component`). However, excluding beans defined via `@Bean` from specific `@WebMvcTest`s is not as easy. Instead of excluding those beans on my test classes I have to make sure that they're not picked up by the slicing and then include them manually. One way of doing this is to group beans into different `@Configuration` classes based on how I will need to include or exclude them in the tests. However, I'm starting to compromise project structure, by creating unneeded `@Configuration` classes that maybe don't make a lot of sense, due to testing framework limitations.

What about mocking?
In some situations, like the one described in the top of this question, mocking is not appropriate. Mocking a `javax.servlet.Filter` doesn't make a lot of sense since you need to call the rest of the chain filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your dependency injection well. All dependencies for a Component or a Bean should be injected via Constructor object. By doing this, in your test cases when you create an object of the testing class, it will expect you to pass all beans that is needed for that class. You can then pass in a mocked class or a null value based on your logic.